# Android Use local CSS to display html String

Tags: java, android

Ok so what i do is the following:

i have a html string i show in a WebView like this:

`webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",htmlText, "text/html","utf-8", null);`

i also have a local css file i want to apply to that html String in the webView.

i looked this up for a while but no solution seemed to work.

There should be a way to save the css file in the assets folder and call it from somwhere but i dont have an idea how.

and suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write anything in the assets folder.

Since you have both the html and the css, I think you can insert css text into the head tag some how like this way

```
int pos = htmlText.toLowerCase().indexOf("</head>");
if(pos != -1) {
    String newHtmlText = htmlText.substring(0, pos) + String.format("<style>%s</style>", cssText) + htmlText.substring(pos + "</head>".length());
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",newHtmlText , "text/html","utf-8", null);
}
```

disclaimer: untested :))

Comment: since i didnt have all the tags i added them as in my answer below. but you are correct, this is how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since i didnt have a  nor  nor  tag i just added them and put the style in the  and my html-text in a  like this:

`String htmlWithCss = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">" +css +"</style></head><body>" + htmlText +"</body></html>";`

and displayed it in the webView like this:

`webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlWithCss, "text/html","utf-8", null);`

This is just to show how to do it when you have blank html-formated text wothout tags around it. i will acceppt J.S. Taylor's answer nevertheless since it showed me basicly what to do.